# How can I create several ExtJs apps without duplicating the Framework

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-cmd, extjs6

I'm developing some [Extjs 6](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/) applications. I'm using [Sench Cmd 6](http://docs.sencha.com/cmd/6.x/) for creating new application. For every project, It creates a new copy of my lilbrary files. I want to re use the library files rather than duplicate them.

```
| -- library files
| -- Project 1  
| -- Project 2  
| -- etc.
```

***How can I do it***?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create first a **workspace**. Then any **app** as you want. Would be something like

```
sencha -sdk "/Sencha/ext-6.0.0" generate workspace "/dev/workspace/"
sencha -sdk "/Sencha/ext-6.0.0" generate app Project1 "/dev/workspace/proj1"
sencha -sdk "/Sencha/ext-6.0.0" generate app Project2 "/dev/workspace/proj2"
```

If you want to share a library between each app, you can add it in the "classpath" array inside **app.json**.

Comment: Can you help me [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31398112/how-can-i-add-geoext3-to-extjs-6-mvvm-architecture) too?

Comment: I think there is a problem either in the title of the question or the answer which is accepted. Because title gets people here "without cmd" and the answer says "with cmd". So why it is accepted or if it is the answer why the question is still "without"?

Comment: I assumed it was a misunderstanding or unknown fonctionnality of Cmd. So maybe it doesn't answer how to "create without sencha cmd", but it seems to solve the initial problem.

Comment: The answer of @PomPom is the only right answer because that is also the way that Sencha promotes it. It is very unwise to develop Ext JS applications without Sencha CMD.