# Ext 6 without Sencha Cmd - how to drop an Ext 6 component into existing app?

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs6

First, I want to acknowledge the existence of this question:

- [How can I create several ExtJs apps without duplicating the Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31376297/how-can-i-create-new-extjs-6-application-without-sencha-cmd)

However, you'll notice that, despite the title, the accepted answer is one using Sencha Cmd :).

With that out of the way, I have an existing application where I would like to make use of one or two Ext 6 components. This application will not be a "Sencha Ext JS application" in the sense that it was not initially built out with Cmd and I have no intention of refactoring to make use of Cmd. In fact, I would prefer that Cmd not be part of my build process if at all possible.

**Is there a supported pathway to cherry-picking Ext 6 components for a non "Ext JS application"?** With e.g. Ext 4 and earlier you could just include `ext-all-debug.[js|css]` and get going. It was also possible to generate a lean file for production using just the source files necessary without necessarily using Cmd.

Comment: As long as you know all classes being used, you can always import them using `Ext.require('')`. Add ext.js to your main JS file and a link to your CSS theme. However using Sencha CMD is way easier, it will manage all classes and file paths for you, I really can't think of a single reason not to use it.

Comment: Thanks @GuilhermeLopes - I've since found where the actual CSS files are located. It's no excuse for overlooking them but they're in a fairly non-intuitive spot (at least for this human) and that fact makes me think I'm doing a thing I am not meant to be doing :). Perhaps I am just misunderstanding how Sencha Cmd is meant to be used - can you point to an example where Cmd is utilized in an application that is not fully Ext? Other reasons not to use it might include not wanting extra dependencies (mostly Java and Ruby).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36472759/how-to-upgarde-my-extjs-application-from-4-to-6/36482163#36482163